# Tiling flat-topped hexagons

Tags: html, css

I found James Tauber's great [CSS hexagon tutorial](https://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html). I would like to use the pseudo element method shown at the end of the page to create a flat topped hexagon grid that would fill out the whole viewport. The code I've written for the hexagon itself is as follows:

```
.hex {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin-left: 8vw;
}

.hex:before,
.hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-top: 12.5vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12.5vw solid transparent;
}

.hex:before {
  border-right: 9vw solid #64C7CC;
  right:15vw;
}

.hex:after {
    border-left: 9vw solid #64C7CC;
    left:15vw;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytnkhwg5/).

I am having trouble combining the pseudo element method with the tiling example shown in the tutorial. How can I repeat the shape to fill out the page - even the small gaps that they will leave near the edges of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ytnkhwg5/1/)

```css
.hex {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 12vw;
}

.hex:before,
.hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-top: 12.5vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12.5vw solid transparent;
}

.hex:before {
  border-right: 9vw solid #64C7CC;
  right:15vw;
}

.hex:after {
    border-left: 9vw solid #64C7CC;
    left:15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">
</div>

<div class="hex">
</div>
```